# prevent/block direct access to a thank you page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

how to prevent/block direct access to a thank you page, only access if redirected from submiiting a form (in a different page)?

where should i insert this method mention in the next link

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290234/prevent-block-direct-access-to-a-thank-you-page/290237

```
add_action('template_redirect', function(){
  if ( ! is_page(12345)) {// ID of the thank you page
    return;
  }
  if (wp_get_referer() == 'URL_OF_FORM') {// coming from the form, so all is fine
    return;
  }

  // we are on thank you page
  // visitor is not coming from form
  // so redirect to home
  wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your first page is page1.php and contains below code

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="blabla">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now when the user enters the form value will redirect to page2.php and here you go below to with the code to see if user have gone through form or entered link. You can achieve this by isset() in php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['blabla']))
{
//process your code
}
else
{
echo "Session Expired<br>";
echo "Click <a href='./page1.php'>here</a> to fill the form";
}
?>
```

Comment: If this answer is what you want, accept the answer for your question also vote it up if you feel satisfaction with the explanation.

Comment: Hello, my thanks page is WordPress page,
where should i insert the code?
Thanks!

Comment: I have added all the information below .Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code top of your thank you page. This is the most efficient & compact code to fulfill your requirement.

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST)):
wp_redirect( home_url() ); 
exit;
endif;
?>
```

Note: `wp_redirect()` does not exit automatically. Always use `exit;` after `wp_redirect()` function.

Comment: Hello,
where to put this code?   in functions.php of theme?  Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the slug for your thank you page?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? "slug for your thank you page" . I have a landing page with contact form 7. after user submit the form, the user go to thanks page and see the coupon code. I wont to prevent/block direct access to a "thank you page" only from landing page. thank a lot!!

Comment: Tell me the last url segment or permalink of your "thank you page"